# Bootstrap Datepicker maximum selection of N days

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've got datepicker with option multidate and I want to define maximum days which user can select, for example 5 days, other days should be disabled. It should happen dynamically - user can select arbitrary 5 days and then other days should be blocked. How can I do that ?

Comment: Which version of datepicker are you using?  There are a few.

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ this one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [documentation for the bootstrap-datepicker plugin](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#multidate) you are using, it looks like if you just do `multidate: 5` "*the picker will limit how many dates can be selected to that number, dropping the oldest dates from the list when the number is exceeded.*"

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
      multidate: 5
});
```

As for disabling the days once 5 are selected, rather than dropping the oldest...I am not sure if that is possible. You might be able to do something like this (but not sure, as you would have to pass in a big array of dates):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
      multidate: 5
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
    //some function here to disable dates once 5 are selected
});
```

Hope this helps.